# what does it mean? One way to degenerate Toric Ideals is to read them as initial ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry

"One way to degenerate Toric Ideals is to read them as initial ideals"

Does anyone have any idea what this sentence tells? any examples.. I do not even know what it means to degenerate Toric Ideal! It would be really helpful if one can help me to get the idea because I can not find by searching in google.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the context? What material is the sentence from?

Comment: I have an ideal in the ring of polynomials and I have to find that how many toric initial ideals it has. But at first step "toric initial ideal" is not clear for me that what it is. Then I asked someone and this was the hint "One way to degenerate Toric Ideals is to read them as initial ideals"

Comment: I know what is initial ideal and I know what is Toric ideal. but I do not know what is toric initial ideal!!

Comment: A toric ideal is generated by binomials. Given an ordering on monomials, you can compute the least monomial in each binomial generator of your ideal. Then take the ideal generated by these least monomials. My guess is this is what they are referring to as a toric initial ideal.

Comment: For certain special weight vectors, the initial ideal will not be monomial. For those special vectors, those for which the initial ideal is binomial are called toric initial ideals. There is a lot of information in Sturmfels' book "Polytopes and Gröbner bases".